# Load FULL docx from Base64 with javascript API

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to load a complete docx document from a remote server with a Word Addin.

Therefore I'm using the code:

> thisDocument.body.insertFileFromBase64(myBase64, "replace");

I was hoping this would load the complete document including headers , footers, fonts, settings. But now I see this will only add content to the body.

After some more research I found out how to set header and footer as well. It's the same as the body:

> var myHeader =
>   mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary").body.insertFileFromBase64(..)

But that will not help me, since my Base64, retrieved from the server is the complete docx document including headers and footers.

So in short: how so insert a complete docx via Javascript API, so that when I save it again this will result in the same docx. I would expect a Document.InsertFileFromBase64 function, but there isn't. Only on body level that function exists

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this GitHub repository and search for 'createDocument':
[createDocument](https://github.com/OfficeDev/hands-on-labs/blob/master/O3652/O3652-2%20Deep%20Dive%20in%20Office%20Word%20Add-ins/Completed%20Solutions/Build2016/StatementOfWorkLab/StatementOfWork2Web/Home.js/)

This feature is still in beta but it does the trick.

URL for Office.js beta:
[OfficeJS beta](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. It's a little bit unstable I noticed, but it's working more or less. The only disadvantage is that it opens an extra new window where my addin is closed. So people have to re-select the plugin to continue editing. Any ideas about how to have my plugin opened right away?

Comment: I would try to open the add-in and then save the document as the template. Perhaps than it appears when a user creates a new document based on that template. But this is guessing!

Comment: At the moment if you're add-in uses Add-in Commands it will not automatically reopen with the document (i.e. if it was opened when the doc was saved & closed, re-open when the doc is opened). If you remove commands it will automatically reopen. Supporting reopening with add-in commands defined is currently being looked into.